# How do I find the average of a certain number of randomly generated numbers in C?

Tags: c

To start of, I'm using repl.it on a chromebook. I'm coding in C and I have no idea what I'm doing.

I have to generate 5 random numbers, then find the mean average of them. I already did the generating 5 random numbers by using a while loop. Now I need to find out how to find the average number. Here is the code I have so far.

```
int n = 1;
float mean = 0;

//create 5 random numbers
srand(time(0));
while( n <= 5)
{   
  dice = rand() % (100 - 1 + 1) + 1.;
  printf("\n%d", dice);
  n++;
}
```

I saw some similar questions but they where all for Python. Thank you to anyone that can help out!

Comment: `average = sum / n`.  `n = 5` in your case.

Comment: First, you need to understand how to calculate the mean by hand. If I give you 5 numbers of my choosing, what are the steps you take to calculate the mean? Describe these steps in words.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Probably need a cast in there, assuming `sum` and `n` are both integers.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's a good point.  It depends on if you care about the remainder.

Comment: This code fails because `dice` is undefined.

Comment: For those commenting explaining how to calculate mean average, I know how I just didn't know how to code it with the loop. Also, this code does work on it's own to generate the numbers, if part of it is missing that just because I didn't copy and paste the whole thing. Thank you for everyone that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem, or get close enough that you can take it from there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  int n = 0;
  double die;
  double sum = 0.0;
  double mean;

  //create 5 random numbers

  srand(time(0));

  for(int n = 0 ; n < 5 ; ++n)
    {   
    die = rand() % (100 - 1 + 1) + 1.;
    printf("%f\n", die);
    sum = sum + die;
    }

  mean = sum / 5.0;

  printf("mean = %f\n", mean);
  }
```

[onlineGDB here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJyIytFcv)